# Cannot stretch the audio file

Tags: python, numpy, audio, scipy, fft

I'm trying to stretch original wav file to k times. In the code below I'm using stretch_factor=2, but in theory I want any k there. My problem is the output.wav not stretched and even audio now is mess. It doesn't work with k<1 where I'm trying to squeeze audio

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.io import wavfile

sampling_rate, signal = wavfile.read("test.wav")

NFFT = 1024
overlap_factor = 4
stretch_factor = 2

hop_size = int(NFFT / overlap_factor)
num_hops = int(np.ceil(float(len(signal)) / hop_size))
pad_size = num_hops * hop_size - len(signal)
z = np.zeros((pad_size,))
pad_signal = np.concatenate((signal, z))

frames = np.array_split(pad_signal, num_hops)

output = np.zeros((0,), dtype=np.float32)
previous_phase = np.zeros((NFFT,), dtype=np.float32)
summed_phase = np.zeros((NFFT,), dtype=np.float32)

for i, frame in enumerate(frames):
    spectrum = np.fft.fft(frame, n=NFFT)
    magnitude = np.abs(spectrum)
    phase = np.angle(spectrum)
    
    frequencies = np.fft.fftfreq(NFFT, d=1.0/sampling_rate)
    frequencies = np.repeat(frequencies, stretch_factor)
    phase_diff = (frequencies[1] - frequencies[0]) * hop_size / sampling_rate

    expected_phase = previous_phase + phase_diff * 2 * np.pi
    delta_phase = phase - expected_phase

    previous_phase = phase.copy()
    summed_phase += delta_phase
    phase_advances = hop_size * summed_phase / (2 * np.pi)
    phase_advances = np.round(phase_advances).astype(int)

    new_spectrum = np.zeros((NFFT,), dtype=np.complex64)
    for j in range(NFFT):
        j2 = j + phase_advances[j]
        if j2 >= 0 and j2 < NFFT:
            new_spectrum[j2] += spectrum[j]
    new_frame = np.fft.ifft(new_spectrum).real

    output = np.concatenate((output, new_frame[:hop_size]))

wavfile.write("output.wav", sampling_rate, output.astype(np.int16))
```

It's my 3rd time when I rewrite code and it is first time when it is finally do something without error. I am new at working with audio so don't know what to do

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Checke [librosa.time_stretch](https://librosa.org/doc/main/generated/librosa.effects.time_stretch.html), if you want it to sound similar. The following example speed up by a factor of two preserving the pitch.

```py
y, sr = librosa.load(librosa.ex('trumpet'))
y_fast = librosa.effects.time_stretch(y, rate=2)
```

Or [librosa.resample](https://librosa.org/doc/main/generated/librosa.resample.html#librosa-resample), if you want the waveform to be streched accordingly. The following example speedup it by a factor of two and moves the pith one octave up.

```
y_up = librosa.resample(y, 2*sr, sr)
```